# Python&Peewee - dynamic where-clause

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee

I am currently working with Flask & Peewee. Imho a good combination, but now i came to a point where peewee seems to "weak" for my Project. Possibly its me, thinking of something in the wrong way :)

The following code describes my problem very well.

```
# dynamic data from somewhere outside my application 
# (does not really matter from where)
# how data really look like
dynamicInput = [(fieldname1 == 'abc'),(fieldname2 == 'def')]

# how data should look like (in a dynamic way)
dynamicInput = [(databasetable.fieldname1 == 'abc'), (databasetable.fieldname2 == 'def')]

# query database with peewee query
model = self.action_meta.model_clothing.select().where(dynamicInput).get()
```

due the missing databasetable reference the where clause is not able
query useful results. By databasetable reference i mean something like **databasetable**.fieldname.

So the question is how do i create a valid where clause dynamically on base of simple dict/list (key value pairs).

Answer (score 2):

Just use DatabaseTable._meta.fields[field_name] or getattr(DatabaseTable, field_name) to get the field object. You can construct expressions dynamically by combining the field object with operators and values.